# Joining tables in SQL where new column name is based on joined table value from another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables and I'm trying to join contents of the second table, into the first. In essence i want to end up with a list of items that contains all fields from the first table, and all relevant rows in the second table, names after column content in the second table.

Table A

```
+----+--------+---------------------+--------+
| ID | Title  |        Date         | Etc... |
+----+--------+---------------------+--------+
|  1 | QWERTY | 0000-00-00:00:00:00 |    ... |
|  2 | TEST   | 0000-00-00:00:00:00 |    ... |
|  3 | ASDF   | 0000-00-00:00:00:00 |    ... |
|  4 | IOP    | 0000-00-00:00:00:00 |    ... |
+----+--------+---------------------+--------+
```

Table B

```
+----+------------+------+------------+
| ID | Table_A_ID | Key  |   Value    |
+----+------------+------+------------+
|  1 |          1 | Name | John       |
|  2 |          2 | Name | Brad       |
|  3 |          1 | DOB  | 2000-01-16 |
+----+------------+------+------------+
```

So I'd like to be able to Select * from Table A and somehow end up with the following

```
+----+--------+---------------------+--------+------+------------+
| ID | Title  |        Date         | Etc... | Name |    DOB     |
+----+--------+---------------------+--------+------+------------+
|  1 | QWERTY | 0000-00-00:00:00:00 |    ... | John | 2000-01-16 |
|  2 | TEST   | 0000-00-00:00:00:00 |    ... | Brad |            |
|  3 | ASDF   | 0000-00-00:00:00:00 |    ... |      |            |
|  4 | IOP    | 0000-00-00:00:00:00 |    ... |      |            |
+----+--------+---------------------+--------+------+------------+
```

**The key thing is that i don't know what the keys are going to be**

Unfortunately I have no idea what this is called to google it, I've been looking through the inner, left, right joins and these don't seem to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You should look again at left join

Comment: The query required would be patterned after the approaches used with EAV (Entity Attribute Value) model.  Consider  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740758/how-make-this-eav-query-to-make-horizontal-result

Comment: You're looking to `pivot` your values columns based on key

Comment: We can demonstrate example SQL for trivial cases, single valued attributes with known (hardcoded) values of `key`. Where those queries don't work, where it gets complicated (and where it seems we are headed with this question) is more generic query, such that when we add a rows `('4','1','foo','fee'),('5','1','foo','fi'),('6','1','bar','soap')` to Table B, we would expect the same query to return additional columns for `foo` and `bar`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with two JOINs on TableB, like :

```
SELECT
    ta.id,
    ta.date,
    ta.etc,
    tb.value Name,
    td.value DOB
FROM
    tableA ta
    INNER JOIN tableB tb ON tb.table_a_id = tb.id AND tb.key = 'Name'
    INNER JOIN tableB td ON td.table_a_id = ta.id AND td.key = 'DOB'
```

With this query, only records that do have a Name and a DOB in TableB will be displayed. If you want to avoid filtering out these "incomplete" records, you can use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN.

Comment: In the case of a missing attribute, we would want to use outer join. (In this query, replace keyword `INNER` with `LEFT`).  For multi-valued attributes, the query can return multiple rows.

Comment: @spencer7593 : absolutely, I was actually updating my answer with this information while you were commenting

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.*, 
(select TOP 1  b.DOB from b where b.table_a_id = a.id and b.key = 'dob'), 
(select TOP 1 b.ame from b where b.table_a_id = a.id and b.key = 'name') 
from a
```

You have to use sub-selects to achieve that results

Comment: This is one approach. But it's not the only one. There are other query patterns that will achieve an equivalent result. i.e. OP does *not* "have to use sub-selects" to achieve this result.  (Note that this query will throw an error for multi-valued attributes. A subquery in the SELECT list will cause an error if it returns more than one row. To avoid potential error, consider adding LIMIT 1 to each subquery.)

Comment: Spencer: yes you're right, but i assumed the Pk set on the tables would block those type of errors.

Comment: I didn't see any indication that we were guaranteed uniqueness.  One of the benefits of the EAV model, one of the reasons that the EAV model is implemented is to support multi-valued attributes.

Comment: @spencer Edited with your suggestion

Comment: `TOP 1` is Transact-SQL (Microsoft SQL Server) syntax, doesn't work in MySQL. The MySQL equivalent is to add **`LIMIT 1`** at the end of the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to pivot the keyed values.  You can do that manually like this:

```
select a.*
     , max(case b.key when 'Name' then b.value end) Name
     , max(case b.key when 'DOB' then b.value end) DOB
  from TableA a
  left join TableB b
    on a.id = b.table_a_id
  group by a.id
      , a.title
      , a.date
      , a.etc
```

The above query will work if you only have one of each attribute for a given record in TableA, otherwise it will give you the largest value.  If you want multiple values, you can generate a sequence for each attribute as shown in the subselect named B below:

```
select a.ID
     , b.Seq
     , a.Title
     , a.Date
     , a.Etc
     , max(case b.key when 'Name' then b.value end) Name
     , max(case b.key when 'DOB' then b.value end) DOB
  from TableA a 
  left join (select @Seq:=case
                       when @aid=b.Table_A_ID and @key=b.key
                       then @Seq + 1
                       else 1
                     end Seq
                   , @aid:=b.Table_A_ID Table_A_ID
                   , @key:=b.key `Key`
                   , b.value
                from tableB b
               order by table_a_id, b.key) b
     on a.id = b.table_a_id
  group by a.id, a.title, a.date, a.etc, b.Seq;
```

This is different than @GMB's response in that it will return each attribute only once with nulls in rows where there are fewer values per attribute whereas @GMB's solution will return the CROSS product of all attributes for a given row.