# What is the proper MySQL way to take data from 4 rows, 1 column, and separate into 9 columns?

Tags: mysql, rows

I've studied and tried days worth of SQL queries to find "something" that will work. I have a table, apj32_facileforms_subrecords, that uses 7 columns. All the data I want to display is in 1 column - "value". The "record" displays the number of the entry. The "title" is what I would like to appear in the header row, but that's not as important as "value" to display in 1 row based upon "record" number.
I've tried a lot of CONCAT and various Pivot queries, but nothing seems to do more than "get close" to what I'd like as the end result.
Here's a screen shot of the table:
[image]

The output "should" be linear, so that 1 row contains 9 columns:
Project; Zipcode; First Name; Last Name; Address; City; Phone; E-mail; Trade (in that order). And the values in the 9 columns come from "value" as they relate to the "record" number.

I know there are LOT of examples that are similar, but nothing I've found covers taking all the values from "value" and CONCAT to 1 row.

This works to get all the data I want - SELECT `record`,`value` FROM `apj32_facileforms_subrecords` WHERE (`record` IN (`record`,`value`)) ORDER BY `record`
But the values are still in multiple rows. I can play with that query to get just the values, but I'm still at a loss to get them into 1 row. I'll keep playing with that query to see if I can figure it out before one of the experts here shows me how simple it is to do that.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: StackOverflow has numerous questions about querying Entity-Attribute-Value model . I suggest that you consider searching "eav pivot query"  or "eav horizontal query".  Two popular approaches to achieving a result are 1) conditional aggregation and 2) correlated subqueries in the SELECT list. As to getting "all the values", if that is meaning executing a SELECT statement that returns a dynamic (variable) number of columns... this is *not* possible in a single SQL SELECT statement. The number of columns and the names of the columns returned must necessarily be specified by the SELECT statement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740758/how-make-this-eav-query-to-make-horizontal-result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How make this eav query to make horizontal result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740758/how-make-this-eav-query-to-make-horizontal-result)

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL to flatten an EAV model representation into a relational representation can be somewhat convoluted, and not very efficient.

Two commonly used approaches are conditional aggregation and correlated subqueries in the SELECT list. Both approaches call out for careful indexing for suitable performance with large sets.

---

**correlated subqueries** example

Here's an example of the correlated subquery approach, to get one value of the "zipcode" attribute for some records

```
 SELECT r.id 
      , ( SELECT v1.value
            FROM `apj32_facileforms_subrecords` v1
           WHERE v1.record = r.id 
             AND v1.name   = 'zipcode'
           ORDER BY v1.value LIMIT 0,1
        ) AS `Zipcode`
   FROM ( SELECT 1 AS id ) r
```

Extending that, we repeat the correlated subquery, changing the attribute identifier ('firstname' in place of 'zipcode'. looks like we we could also reference it by element, e.g. `v2.element = 2`

```
 SELECT r.id
      , ( SELECT v1.value
            FROM `apj32_facileforms_subrecords` v1
           WHERE v1.record = r.id 
             AND v1.name   = 'zipcode'
           ORDER BY v1.value LIMIT 0,1
        ) AS `Zipcode`

      , ( SELECT v2.value
            FROM `apj32_facileforms_subrecords` v2
           WHERE v2.record = r.id 
             AND v2.name   = 'firstname'
           ORDER BY v2.value LIMIT 0,1
        ) AS `First Name`  

      , ( SELECT v3.value
            FROM `apj32_facileforms_subrecords` v3
           WHERE v3.record = r.id 
             AND v3.name   = 'lastname'
           ORDER BY v3.value LIMIT 0,1
        ) AS `Last Name`

   FROM ( SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 2 ) r
```

returns something like

```
id  Zipcode  First Name  Last Name
--  -------  ----------  ---------
 1  98228    David       Bacon
 2  98228    David       Bacon
```

---

**conditional aggregation** approach example

We can use `GROUP BY` to collapse multiple rows into one row per entity, and use conditional tests in expressions to "pick out" attribute values with aggregate functions.

```
 SELECT r.id
      , MIN(IF(v.name  = 'zipcode'   ,v.value,NULL)) AS `Zip Code`
      , MIN(IF(v.name  = 'firstname' ,v.value,NULL)) AS `First Name`
      , MIN(IF(v.name  = 'lastname'  ,v.value,NULL)) AS `Last Name`
   FROM ( SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 2 ) r
   LEFT
   JOIN `apj32_facileforms_subrecords` v
     ON v.record = r.id
  GROUP
     BY r.id
```

For more portable syntax, we can replace MySQL `IF()` function with more ANSI standard `CASE` expression, e.g.

```
      , MIN(CASE v.name WHEN 'zipcode'   THEN v.value END) AS `Zip Code`
```

---

Note that MySQL does not support SQL Server `PIVOT` syntax, or Oracle `MODEL` syntax, or Postgres `CROSSTAB` or `FILTER` syntax.

To extend either of these approaches to be dynamic, to return a resultset with a variable number of columns, and variety of column names ...  that is not possible in the context of a single SQL statement. We could separately execute SQL statements to retrieve information, that would allow us to dynamically construct a SQL statement of a form show above, with an explicit set of columns to be returned.

---

The approaches outline above return a more traditional relational model, (individual columns each with a value).

**non-relational** munge of attributes and values into a single string

If we have some special delimiters, we could munge together a representation of the data using GROUP_CONCAT function

As a rudimentary example:

```
 SELECT r.id
      , GROUP_CONCAT(v.title,'=',v.value ORDER BY v.name) AS vals
   FROM ( SELECT 1 AS id ) r
   LEFT
   JOIN `apj32_facileforms_subrecords` v
     ON v.record = r.id
    AND v.name in ('zipcode','firstname','lastname')
  GROUP
     BY r.id
```

To return two columns, something like

```
 id   vals
 --   --------------------------------------------------- 
  1   First Name=David,Last Name=Bacon,Zip Code=98228
```

We need to be aware that the return from GROUP_CONCAT is limited to `group_concat_max_len` bytes.  And here we have just squeezed the balloon, moving the problem to some later processing, to parse the resulting string. If we have any equal signs or commas that appear in the values, it's going to make a mess of parsing the result string. So we will have to properly escape any delimiters that appear in the data, so that GROUP_CONCAT expression is going to get more involved.

Comment: Thank you for being so quick to respond. You don't sound very convinced that either option is a great idea. Would it be better to do what I'm attempting using a Php function? The data is coming from the db and then displayed in the front end of the Web site for users to review. It's necessary that I include (in column 1 since id is of no value) the date and time. I can see your "correlated subqueries example" as the best option thus far. But I'll await your feedback as to whether or not that's a good resolve.

Comment: You are right that i'm not convinced that SQL is the best tool for unwinding an EAV model back into a relational representation. The two approaches I posted are typical, and both are workable. Both cry out for suitable indexes (use EXPLAIN to see the execution plans).  My example queries returned  `id` as the first column as an identifier for the entity, in case we are returning more than one entity row. Certainly, other expressions could be returned, the inline view in my examples would typically be replaced with a reference to the entity table, and a WHERE clause to limit entity rows...

Comment: With the correlated subquery approach, we can return multi-valued attributes. Consider an entity that has two or more values for zipcode. We can repeat the `zipcode` subquery and change LIMIT 0,1 to LIMIT 1,1 to get the second value, repeat again with LIMIT 2,1 to get the third. The downside is that it's a lot more SQL to build.  With the conditional aggregation approach, we have a lot less SQL syntax,  just one reference to the values table.

Comment: My personal opinion:  if the traditional relational model was insufficient to support the requirements, and we required an EAV model, why would we want to use SQL to unwind the EAV model and marshal it back into a traditional relational modell representation... which is what we were *avoiding* by using EAV. Seems to me a Goldberg-esque rigmarole...  to get the benefits of the relational model by way of the drawbacks of EAV, and trying to disguise the complexity by abusing SQL. (Again, this is just my personal opinion. This does not invalidate differing opinions.)

Comment: Also note that the two example queries return attribute value columns (`Zip Code`, `First Name` as the datatype of the `value` column, which looks to be character type. Note that the ORDER BY in the subquery (and the MIN/MAX of the conditional aggregation) comparisons operate on the datatype of `value`, such that e.g. `"42"`  will be considered greater than `"100"`.  We may want to take into account the "datatype" of the attribute, and include syntax to do datatype conversions e.g. string to numeric, string to date, before ORDER BY / MIN/MAX comparisons, further complicating the queries.

Comment: I understand that the attempt to use SQL is not the right tool. I've got a developer for some of the software I use who is attempting to do this the "right way". I don't know the terminology, but what I believe is the method is taking the data, putting it into another table that is linear, then extracting the desired columns of data. I'm guessing that would be your approach also. Thank you, Spencer, for all your input. I'll let you know if this guy can produce what I need. He created Tubulizer, so I'm guessing he has a good idea of manipulating db data.

Comment: I wish you a favorable outcome with your development efforts. I did not mean to say that its wrong to use to SQL to marshal an EAV model. My objection is primarily to the notion that the SQL to do that will be easy or simple or efficient because SQL has builtin in features for doing that -- it doesn't. SQL is designed to work with the relational model, not designed to work with an EAV model. Its almost coincidental that an EAV model is implemented in an RDBMS.

Comment: Oh I don't see anything that you've stated as anything but helpful. As I mentioned, I decided that, in "my" words, doing all that is the wrong approach. I'm actually working on a Joomla extension now that is a "ContentBuilder" from Crosstec which allows me to create the form and display the submissions. Crosstec also created the form only software that pushed the data into the one column structure to make things next to impossible to display. Even they said don't try, and instead, use the ContentBuilder software. Thank you for your help.